# Call a list in code behind of ASPX , in javascript code in foreach loop?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2012

I have the following aspx.cs :

```
public partial class BarChart 
{
    public class LabelsDetail
    {
        public string LabelId { get;set; }
        public string LabelDesc { get; set; }
    }
    public List<LabelsDetail> LabelsDetails { get; set; }

    public void InsertDataToLabelsDetails()
    {
        // Data comes from somewhere into "LabelsDetails"

    }

}
```

and the following JS code in the ASPX page :

```
        function setupBarChart(JQObjectContainer, JsonData) {
            var hashTableSize = <%=this.LabelsDetails.Count%>;
            var hashtable = {};

            if (hashTableSize != 'undefined' && hashTableSize > 0)
            {
                for (var item in <%=this.LabelsDetails%>)
                { 
                    hashtable[item.LabelId] = item.LabelDesc;
                }
            }

}
```

How can I do a foreach on a server side list in the client side ?

At the moment I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unterminated template literal`
When I try to loop on the server side list (`this.LabelsDetails`) .

Thanks

Comment: `this.LabelsDetails` is just going to turn into the typename, as if you had called `.ToString()` on it. You need to convert it to JSON, embed it in your JavaScript, convert from JSON back to a JavaScript array, and loop over that. Or even better, retrieve the list via AJAX calls to [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api).

Comment: you are trying to mix server side code and client side code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must convert your collection to a notation that JavaScript will understand, to do that you can use [`JavaScriptSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or any other JSON converter:

```
var collection = new[]{
    new { Name = "a" },
    new { Name = "b" },
    new { Name = "c" },
    new { Name = "d" }
};

System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer s = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

Console.WriteLine(s.Serialize(collection));
```

This will output `[{"Name":"a"},{"Name":"b"},{"Name":"c"},{"Name":"d"}]` whhich is a valid array notation for JavaScript. You also can improve the way you iterate in JS:

```
var array = <%=new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(this.LabelsDetails)%>;
for(var x=0;x<array.length;x++)
{ 
    hashtable[array[x].LabelId] = array[x].LabelDesc;
}
```

For...In is not good to iterate arrays in JS, it's not the same as `foreach` in C#.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

> Array iteration and for...in
>
> Note: for..in should not be used to iterate over an Array where the
>   index order is important. Array indexes are just enumerable properties
>   with integer names and are otherwise identical to general Object
>   properties. There is no guarantee that for...in will return the
>   indexes in any particular order and it will return all enumerable
>   properties, including those with non–integer names and those that are
>   inherited.

However, it might be worth to review your approach and use other technologies to do the connection between client-side and server-side.

Comment: Thanks , but this is not an array , it's a string .I need to loop on array , not a string ...

Comment: did you try it? You're getting a memory object and converting it to a string which will be written in JavaScript and interpreted as a literal notation of array. For the JS compiler it will not be a string, it will be an array...

Comment: Yes I did , however each iteration the `item` is `0`  , meaning you have the JS array , but the `item` holds nothing .

Comment: the problem is your loop, `for...in` in JS is not the same as c# `foreach`, updated the answer to explain that

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
function setupBarChart(JQObjectContainer, JsonData) {
            var hashTableSize = <%=this.LabelsDetails.Count%>;
            var hashtable = {};
            var json = <%=new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(this.LabelsDetails)%>;
            if (hashTableSize != 'undefined' && hashTableSize > 0)
            {
                for (var key in json)
                { 
                    hashtable[json[key].LabelId] = json[key].LabelDesc;
                }

            }
}
```